# Singleton pattern

Tags: evaluation

How can I implement the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) in Mathematica in order to ensure that a symbol is not redefined if it's already defined ?

This can be useful for example with global variables in packages that we reload with Get when developing.

Comment: My understanding has been that the singleton pattern is a way to introduce global variables in the wolrd where everything is an object, so is basically a pretty ugly way to work around their absence in languages like Java. What advantages do you think it brings to the languages which natively have global state? As to your specific question, good old `Protect` should do for external use, while for the purposes of package reloading, I've seen the code similar to you answer (without making it a function), or one can `Uprotect` things at the start and `Protect` at the end of a package.

Comment: I just saw the same code several times and realized it was the same thing as a singleton, I found it interesting and posted it.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite easy with a little bit of metaprogramming, symbol is replaced unevaluated in the body, instead of evaluating it in the arguments and replacing it in the body with a value, like what would happen if the function didn't have a HoldXXX attribute like in the usual evaluation used by most functions.

```
SetAttributes[InitSingleton,HoldAll];
InitSingleton[symbol_,value_]:=
    If[!ValueQ@symbol,
        symbol = value
        ,
        symbol
    ];

InitSingleton[currentDate,DateString[]]
InitSingleton[currentDate,DateString[]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If I want `foo` to be immutable after gets bound to a value, I write

```
foo = 42;
Protect[foo];
```

Now, observe what happens when I attempt to bind `foo` to a different value.

```
foo = 0; foo
```

> Set::wrsym: Symbol foo is Protected. >>
>       42

or clear it

```
foo =.; foo
```

> Set::wrsym: Symbol foo is Protected. >>
>       42